# Python filter not working

Tags: python

I am trying to run following code.

```
>>>left = [1,2,3]
>>>mid = [1,2]
>>>filter(lambda x: x not in left, mid)
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: filter() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Why is this? Filter clearly takes two arguments.

Comment: Check to see if you reassigned `filter` earlier in your code.

Comment: Wow that's absolutely correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of python are you using? It works on 2.4.3

```
 Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan 14 2011, 00:20:04) 
 [GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> left=[1,2,3]
 >>> mid=[1,2]
 >>> filter(lambda x: x not in left, mid)
 []
```

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer.